# Gstreamer streaming pipeline optimisation to reduce latency

Tags: gstreamer

I am currently streaming my entire Surface Pro's desktop to another device on my local network.
I would like to optimize and reduce lag as much as possible between the two devices.
I currently have arround 500ms latency between what I have on the screen of the streaming device, and what I see on the device receiving and displaying the stream.
I have used UDP instead of TCP and encoded with H264.

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe dxgiscreencapsrc width=2880 height=1920 monitor=0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! 
videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1440,height=960 ! videoconvert ! 
videocrop top=50 left=20 bottom=280 right=20 ! queue ! mfh264enc rc-mode=0 low-latency=true 
bitrate=1500 gop-size=10 ! queue ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=49800
```